# How to use the bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm fairly new to Angular.js (or to web programming in general). I got a pretty basic problem - I'd like to include a date picker in my application. For this purpose, I try to set up the bootstrap datepicker:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#

I have the jQuery and Bootstrap dependencies included:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blog.css">
    <script src="angular-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/blogController.js"></script>
```

I don't really understand, how am I supposed to use it from now on? I can include some input field in my HTML template, but how exactly do I call the script that calls the date picker widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `id` or a `class` to your `input` field and use that as a selector once you call the datepicker.

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

In your JS:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Yes, that I know, but where in my JS? Just about anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
full code just test

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
              href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="well">
            <div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append"> 
                <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text"></input> 
                <span class="add-on"> 
                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"> </i> 
                </span> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({pickTime: false});
            });
        </script>
       </body>
</html>
```